# SceneKit scene higher than expected FPS on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, scenekit, frame-rate, sceneview

My macOS app has two `SceneKit` `sceneViews`, and when they're empty, they both appear to be running at an FPS of 120.

I've not manually set `preferredFramesPerSecond` anywhere in my code. The default for `preferredFramesPerSecond` is 60 FPS, so I'm a bit confused as to why the FPS is double than that - anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The online documentation seems to be out-of-date.
Here's what you can find in the header documentation for `SCNView.h`:

> The default value is 0 which means the display link will fire at the native cadence of the display hardware.

Comment: Oh, that's very interesting - thank you for that! Any recommendations on how best to set a proper value?